# Inherited constructor (using) and move

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

**UPDATE: it seems it's my fault, I didn't installed correctly CTP. MS weren't able to reproduce the bug.**

I'd like to move a variable from a derived class to my base class (there are multiple classes between them)

Usually, I would pass the argument by const&, but I'm trying to pass it by value and move it down the hierarchy, avoiding a copy.

Here are my classes:

```
#include <string>

class base {
 public:
    explicit base(std::string url) : url_{std::move(url)} {}
    // prevent copy
    base(const base&) = delete;
    base& operator=(const base&) = delete;
    virtual ~base() {}

protected:
    std::string url_;
};

class derived : public base {
 public:
    using base::base;
};

class derived_final : public derived {
 public:
    using derived::derived;
    explicit derived_final(std::string url) :
        derived{std::move(url)}
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
};


int main() {
    derived_final df { "test" };
}
```

and the log:

```
e:\project\test\main.cpp(25) : error C2664: 'derived::derived(const derived &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'const derived &'
        Reason: cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'const derived'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

I also tried adding a move constructor to base, aswell as an op=.

But derived_final tries to use derived's copy constructor with std::string as parameter, when I try to move url to derived in derived_final's constructor.

Any ideas why this is happening?
I'm using msvc 2013 with CTP (for "using" support).

source here: https://bitbucket.org/syl/c-11-inherited-constructor-and-move/src

Comment: Can you include `main()` as well? I ask because with uniform-init `derived_final df{ "test" };` I'm given no such invalid copy-ctor messaging. And I'm not entirely clear why you're not using rval-refs for those args in the first place.

Comment: Isn't the problem here that you do `using derived::derived;` as well as define `explicit derived_final(std::string url)` - doesn't that make 2 ctors in `derived_final` with the exact same signature? I haven't used this feature yet

Comment: I updated the post with a full listing and the error message. I tried to remove "explicit" but I still get the same error. @WhozCraig I also tried to add a rvalue constructor, still the same error. it's still trying use the (const derived&)

Comment: So [this pukes](http://ideone.com/vmm7iE) on VS2013 ? How positively odd. Perhaps [this doesn't](http://ideone.com/TtECeM) ?

Comment: both do, damn... the CTP is in alpha/beta, maybe that's why.

Comment: @Dave That's not a problem because if there's a user defined constructor with the same signature as an inherited constructor, then the former will be used instead of the latter. In this example, the `using derived::derived;` declaration is useless because there is only one constructor (that takes an `std::string`) that could be inherited from `derived` but the definition of `derived_final(std::string url)` means it will not be inherited.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The signature `base(std::string)` is preferred here.  I would only want to go to the trouble of defining `base(const std::string&)` and `base(std::string&&)` instead if those overloads needed to do different things.

Comment: @Syl Damn. That's an incredibly strange example of `rref` usage. Saves you from writing another constructor but takes a toll of additional string `move-ctor` call on every `ctor` propagation. Not so good, especially for `MSVC` which has pretty big `sizeof(std::string)`.

Comment: fyi, it also doesn't work with const std::string&, because msvc still tries to use the copy constructor (const derived&) with the string.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a MSVC bug. GCC reports no errors.

Comment: I installed Nov 2013 CTP: http://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/1xhjwo/new_c_student_using_visual_studio_express_2012/cfbogip?context=3

Comment: We're back to 'MSCV bug' then :)